# Spring beans and threads

Tags: multithreading, spring, javabeans

I have to create a progress bar in a webapp. I need a thread that do the work and a controller that tests this thread to get his status.
How to set it using beans (inside that thread I need to autowire some services)? Can I use thread as non-singleton bean?
Thank you.

Comment: what is the scope of those "progress bar" task? are those thread bounded to your session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a small wrapping class for this.  You could have all of your setters in the class to handle the injected services, you could use `InitializingBean` to start the thread, and you can inject the bean into other classes so they could call getters on `volatile` or `synchronized` fields.  Something like:

```
public class ProgressBar implements InitializingBean, Runnable, DisposableBean {
    private volatile int someField;
    private Thread thread;
    // start the thread after the properties are set
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        // maybe make it a daemon thread
        // thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    // stop it when spring is shutting down
    public void destroy() {
        thread.interrupt();
    }
    public void run() {
       ... thread code goes here
    }
    // spring setter
    public void setSomeService(SomeService someService) {
       this.someService = someService;
    }
    // getter used by other beans to get some value from this class
    public int getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }
}
```

You could also use some of spring's timer classes for this of course although they work better for repetitive tasks that run every so often.

Comment: But the thread must be a non-singleton bean? How to define it with annotation?

Comment: So you want many of them?  Then you should turn it into a `FactoryBean` instead.  http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/09/whats-a-factorybean/

Comment: with the implementation above may I need a standard new ProgressBar();?